# What technology do the Harvesters use to achieve FTL travel?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

The Sphere from the movie *Independence Day: Resurgence* is described as traveling across the universe through a **wormhole**.

I was thinking that each alien civilization from *Independence Day* has its own unique technology and science, but I can't remember seeing a description of how the Harvesters travel around the universe.

**How does the Harvester species achieve FTL travel? Via wormhole or some other technology entirely?**

Comment: The wiki suggests that they also utilise wormhole tech; http://independenceday.wikia.com/wiki/Harvesters

Answer (score 1):

The Harvesters are *suspected* to use wormhole tech, but in-universe it's not confirmed. That being said, there doesn't seem any obvious reason why they *wouldn't.*

> David waited, knowing Okun wouldn’t be able to keep it to himself for long… and he was right.
>   “Interstellar travel.”
>   David nodded. That made sense. The ships had arrived through wormholes, but the humans hadn’t yet found any clue as to how the aliens created them, maintained them, operated them…
>
> ...
>
> “Don’t you think it’s strange that they’re back on the same day, twenty years later?”
>
> “It’s quite simple, actually,” Charlie said, as if he’d spent a lot of time thinking about it—which maybe he had. Jake wouldn’t be surprised. “Orbital mechanics. If they’re using wormholes, our relative position in the rotation of the galaxy could be a factor. June 30th, 1908, the Tunguska Blast, July 3rd, 1947, the Roswell crash, July 2nd, 1996, the Invasion.” He paused, thinking it over. “Or it could just be a coincidence.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Independence Day: Resurgence - Official Novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(book_series)#Independence_Day:_Resurgence)</sup></sub>